# Robot Inventor 51515 - PIN request when connecting via Bluetooth

Tags: mindstorms

Just received the item [51515](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/robot-inventor-51515)

Managed to connect the Mindstorms controller via Bluetooth from mobile without any problems. Great!
Next step, connect from PC.
When I connect from my Windows machine I get Bluetooth PIN prompt.

What PIN should I put in?

[image]

Comment: I didn't get a bluetooth pin prompt on my windows 10, latest update. Which version of windows are you using? Also, what bluetooth setup do you have? Perhaps post a picture of the info available in device manager...

Comment: W10 with all updates installed. And also, I have accepted the prompt from LEGO software to update the firmware for both the brick and all motors.

Comment: Are you trying to pair your Hub directly with your PC or via Mindstorms software?

Comment: Via Mindstorm software and when I do so the prompt for the PIN shows up.

Comment: Sorted. I remove the brick using OS Bluetooth interface. Then went on to once again add it from Lego software and this time it did not ask me for the PIN.
Thanks for your swift help guys!

Answer (score 6):

I removed the brick using Windows Bluetooth panel. Then once again readded the device using Lego software. And this time it did not ask me for the Bluetooth PIN.